# How i can get my signatures from my gmail account? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, gmail-api, signature

Someone can helm me? I need to get(fetch) signature from my gmail in node js,[how signature looks like in gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4kWc.png).
Maybe u know some libs or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the signature of Gmail as follows. The image is from your question.

  [image]
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

Please use `auth` in your script. This sample script uses the method of users.settings.sendAs.list.

```js
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
const res1 = await gmail.users.settings.sendAs.list({ userId: "me" }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
if (!res1) return;
console.log(res1.data);
```

#### Sample script 2:

Please use `auth` in your script. This sample script uses the method of users.settings.sendAs.get .

```js
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
const res2 = await gmail.users.settings.sendAs.get({ userId: "me", sendAsEmail: "### your Email address ###" }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
if (!res2) return;
console.log(res2.data);
```

#### Note:

- This answer supposes that you have already been able to get values from Gmail using Gmail API. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: users.settings.sendAs.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list)
- [Method: users.settings.sendAs.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/get)
- [Node.js quickstart for Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)